# What are the charges/action against sledging in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

[Sledging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sledging_%28cricket%29) is used to diverse a Player's mind from his game and make him difficult to concentrate on his game which affects its performance in the game.

Sledging is used as master weapon by many international cricket teams like Australia,England and West Indies.

> What are the charges specified against the sledging?

a specific time of ban,match fees amount or any other charges.

> Is there any cricketing rules specified for sledging?

I know an incident between Harbhajan–Symonds incident (Monkey-Gate).In which it was considered an offence of sledging Andrew Symonds by Harbhajan Singh in which a three match ban was proposed and then lifted out because of not having a proof but he was charged under Level 2.8 offence (abuse and insult not amounting to racism) to which he pleaded guilty and was fined 50 per cent of his match fees.

> In such a case What if whole team is found guilty ?

will all of them will be considered guilty and banned for playing the considered cricket matches ?

> Who takes the amount of fine ?

the money taken as fine belongs to whom the player who was sledged or the team to which the player belongs or the ICC

Comment: I read the [Law 42 (Fair and unfair play)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-42-fair-and-unfair-play/). But I could not find anything about it. Really looking for a good answer. +1. However, I am not sure if there are *specified* charges for sledging since the sledging can have different level. It's totally up to match referee IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sledging is essentially just trash talk to distract the opposing team/player. It's part of every competitive sport. There are no specific charges or rules for such a thing. That being said, it's commonly mistaken for poor sportsmanship, verbal abuse or personal abuse in which case its taken more seriously. It's then up to the referee to decided how severe it is and what the penalty should be.

Really, it's a hot topic. It's a debate that's been going on for a long time and not just in cricket itself. I think it adds some fun, playful humour and good ol' competition to the game but there is a line, and when it's crossed the ref will make the call.

Comment: banter is part of cricket, seldging isnt going anywhere :o)